# REST JAX-RS handler de errores no captura errores

Tags: rest, tomcat, jax-rs

Actualmente tengo un servicio REST con JAX-RS en tomcat. Ahora quiero que los errores típicos de error 400,405,500,etc sean devueltos en formato JSON y no HTML como lo hace de normal.

Entonces he estado basandome en https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-en/cn/part1/chapter7/exception_handling.html para crear un handler de errores.

Este es un manejador genérico.

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {

 @Override
 public Response toResponse(final WebApplicationException exception) {
    final ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse("Generic excepton", "503",
            "https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html");
    return Response.ok().entity(response).build();
 }
}
```

Y este es uno específico ( aunque sea idéntico)

```
@Provider
public class NotAllowedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotAllowedException> {

 @Override
 public Response toResponse(final NotAllowedException exception) {
    final ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse(exception.getMessage(), "503",
            "https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html");
    return Response.ok().entity(response).build();
 }

}
```

Luego tengo preparado ya para probarlo, para cuando reciba una petición, lance automáticamente una excepción.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response list(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo, @Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
        @PathParam(USER_ID) final Integer userId, @QueryParam("offset") final Integer offset,
        @QueryParam(LIMIT) final Integer limit, @PathParam(OPERATION_LABEL) final String oper) {

    throw new NotAllowedException("test");
    /*Response response;
    if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase(RELOAD_OP)) {
        response = reload();
    } else {

        response = listImplementation(uriInfo, httpHeaders, userId, offset, limit, oper);
    }
    return response;*/
}
```

Lanzó la siguiente petición

```
GET http://localhost:8080/webservice/persons
```

Poniendo un punto de ruptura en WS que espera la llamada veo que llega al `throw new NotAllowedException("test");` pero no llega a entrar a alguno de los dos handlers que he puesto y devuelve el clásico código html.

```
<body><h1>Estado HTTP 405 – Method Not Allowed</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Tipo</b> Informe de estado</p><p><b>mensaje</b> Method Not Allowed</p><p><b>descripción</b> El método HTTP especificado no está permitido para el recurso requerido.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.53</h3></body>
```

¿Alguna idea de por que no me entra en mis handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he descubierto la causa del error. Todo lo que hay puesto es correcto. El problema lo tenia en `web.xml` y en la ubicación de mis handlers

Este es el contenido de  mi web.xml con el problema ya solucionado

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.mjuan.ws.version.base.services,
            com.mjuan.ws.version.v4.services,
            com.mjuan.ws.exception.mappers
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

El problema estaba en que como tenia los mapeadores en un paquete distinto de los servicios web, estos no eran reconocidos por jersey.

Todo se soluciono añadiendo `com.mjuan.ws.exception.mappers` para que jersey reconociese mis mapeadores.

Espero que esta solución le sirva a la gente ya que esta condición la encontré de pura casualidad y en ningún sitio vi que dijese que era necesario.